# Can't decrease local variable in razor ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is my .cshtml file and I am declaring and assigning the value to variable x.
When I click the button with id 'b', I want this variable be used and then decreased with one, but when I debug this project, I see that variable x isn't decreasing. What mistake do I have?

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplicationMVC.Models.Test>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Testing";
    int x = Model.Count() - 1;
}

<script>

<div id="partial">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("Question", Model.ToList()[0])
</div>

<input type="button" id="b" value="next" class="btn btn-default" />

$("#b").click(function () {

    if (@x == 0) {
        window.alert("Finished")
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Subject")'
    }

    window.alert("Value of x is -> " + @x);

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Question", "Test")',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { id: '@Model.ToList()[x].ID' },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#partial").html(result);
        }
    });

    @{ 
        x--;         //this doesn't work...
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That variable x is in C#, running on the server. It never reaches the browser.

You want a variable to decrease when something is clicked in the browser.

Use a Javascript variable instead:

```
<script>
    var x = @(Model.Count() - 1);  // javascript variable, initialised to a value from Razor

    if (x == 0)
    {
       // finished
    }

    window.alert("Value of x is -> " + x);

    x--;
```